# Proguard folder empty

Tags: android, eclipse, export, obfuscation, proguard

I am using Eclipse to build my Android Application. When I export the project as an Android Application I can use my keystore and key to sign the apk just fine. Before exporting I also added the Proguard config location to the properties file, I also changed my Android SDK file path to one without spaces, and I have debuggable set to false in my manifest.

With all of those done, the proguard folder in my project that is created does not contain any files and the Android documentation claims it will contain several.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

What have I missed?

Comment: Does your path contain spaces?

Comment: I changed my SDK path so it doesn't

Comment: Any Eclipse console output to indicate errors with proguard?

Comment: Nope, there was until I changed the SDK path, but it seems to run fine. No errors. The folder is just empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid error on my part. It looked like it was succeeding because it was. Its just the proguard files weren't imported into eclipse so they didn't show up in package explorer. Manually entering workspace I found them.

That is indeed a little embarrassing. Oh well.

Comment: Thankyou, this answer helped me.  PS. Dont be embarrassed, I think they SHOULD show up in the Package Explorer! :-)